# Rails Mysql2::Error: missing quote in field where

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

i have migrate a rails application from Postgres to Mysql and i have this error

```
An ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid occurred in bans#supporters:

  Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'follows.followable_id' in 'where clause': SELECT `users`.* FROM `users`  WHERE (follows.followable_id=37 AND follows.followable_type='Ban')
  app/controllers/bans_controller.rb:120:in `supporters'
```

when i do this in mysql

```
SELECT `users`.* FROM `users`  WHERE ('follows.followable_id'=37 AND 'follows.followable_type'='Ban'
```

it's work

so, how to add quotes around *follows.followable_id* and *follows.followable_type* in rails ?

Thanks,
Gilles

Thanks Fenec
actually in bans_controller i have
`@users = User.following(@ban)`

when i put

```
@users = User.joins(:follows).following(@ban)
```

It's works

Answer (score 0):

It has nothing to do with quotes. You just didn't migrate followable_id column from follows

Comment: ok, but why when i do SELECT `users`.* FROM `users`  WHERE ('follows.followable_id'=37 AND 'follows.followable_type'='Ban' in Mysql, it's work

Comment: how do you generate this query in your controller? you should actually join 'follows' table to make this query works.